# expect in bash script × 16172

Tags: bash

I try to set a expect script in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash


/usr/bin/expect <<- EOD

set router 192.168.0.251
set user admin
set pass test  
set timeout 1000  
set filesave [exec date +%m-%d-%Y]  


spawn telnet $router
send "\n"  
expect "Username:"
send "$user\n"
expect "Password:"  
send "$pass\n"  
expect ">"  
send "en\n"  
expect "Password:"  
send "$pass\n"  

send "term len 0\n"  
log_file $router--$filesave.cfg
send "show running-config\n"  
expect "end\r"  
send "\n"  
log_file
send "exit\n"  
EOD

cat /Users/test/Desktop/python/$router--$filesave.cfg | grep end
exit 0
```

I just got this output

```
./script2 
spawn telnet

telnet> telnet>
```

Comment: What output are you hoping for then.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your shebang from:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/expect
```

and remove:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<- EOD
```

And see if that works.

Update: if you need to have expect run as part of your bash script, either encapsulate the expect code in a separate script with a expect shebang and source it from your bash script, or encode it as in the following example:

```
expect_sh=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh $login@$IP
expect \"password:\"
send \"$password\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"cd $dest_dir\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"chmod +x $server_side_script $other_script\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"./$device_side_script\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"cat $deploy_count\r\" 
expect \"#\"
send \"exit\r\"
")

echo "$expect_sh"
```

Comment: yes this works, but I want to go on with the bash script. So i decided to put it in one script.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that bash is interpreting all the `$variables` before expect sees the script. Thus you're simply spawning `telnet` with no hostname given. Change:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<- EOD
```

to:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<- 'EOD'
```

This has the effect of single-quoting the entire here-document.
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Note also that the next bash command (`cat /Users/...`) relies on variables defined in Expect -- they are not defined in bash. Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

export router=192.168.0.251
export filesave=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)

/usr/bin/expect <<- 'EOD'

set router $env(router)
set filesave $env(filesave)
# the rest stays the same
```